# What is the major difference between Pex vs MsTest?

Tags: mstest, pex

What is the major difference between Pex vs MsTest? 
when to use what?

Comment: From http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions.htm:  Think about Pex **with** VSTS unit testing rather than 'vs'. Pex acts as a plugin for unit test framework by providing parameterized unit tests, but it does not prevent the user from writing 'closed' unit tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Impression is that Pex is a supplement to traditional testing frameworks like MSTest or NUnit, rather than a competing framework.  Threads like this one: [Is Pex (Test generation) really useful tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704669/is-pex-test-generation-really-usefull-tool)
seem to indicate that Pex aids in creating parametrized unit tests driven by data, and in generating tests based on assertions in the tests themselves, but can be used with a variety of frameworks.